# Find lengths of tangents drawn from $(3,-5)$ to the Ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

Find lengths of tangents drawn from $A(3,-5)$ to the Ellipse $\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1$

My try: I assumed the point of tangency of ellipse as $P(5\cos a, 4 \sin a)$

Now Equation of tangent at $P$ is given by

$$\frac{x \cos a}{5}+\frac{ y \sin a}{4}=1$$ whose slope is $$m_1=\frac{-4 \cot a}{5}$$

Also slope of $AP$ is given by

$$m_2=\frac{4 \sin a+5}{5 \cos a-3}$$

So both slopes are equal , with that we get

$$12 \cos a-25 \sin a=20 \tag{1}$$

Now distance $AP$ is given by

$$AP=\sqrt{(3-5 \cos a)^2+(5+4 \sin a)^2}=\sqrt{75-30 \cos a+40 \sin a} \tag{2}$$

Now using $(1)$ we have to find $\cos a$ and $\sin a$ and then substitute in $(2)$ which becomes lengthy.

Any better way?

Comment: No nothing like that, just want to calculate length of tangent to ellipse drawn from point outside it

Comment: The two tangents have distances 3.97 and 4.72 according to geogebra.

Comment: I had misunderstood. But there are two ways to draw a tangent to an ellipse which have no reason to be the same length (unlike the case for a circle) thus in general there are two different answers.

Comment: yes i agree i need those two answers

Comment: Thus your title should be "find lengthS of tangentS...." with a plural.

Answer (score 2):

let $$y=mx+n$$ then the equation of the line through $P(3;-5)$ is given by
$$y=m(x-3)-5$$ plug this in the equation of the Ellipse and solve this equation for $x$, since it should be a tangentline, the discriminante must be Zero
you will get $$16m^2-30m-9=0$$ solve this equation for $m$

Comment: The discriminant should be $16m^2-30m-9$, but your point remains.

Comment: thank you for your hint!

Answer (score 2):

The slope of tangent at a point (x,y) on the ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1$$ is  $$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {-16x}{25y}$$

On the other hand slope of the line passing through $(x,y)$ and $(3,-5)$ is $m = \frac {y+5}{x-3} $
$$  \frac {-16x}{25y}= \frac {y+5}{x-3} \implies 48x-125y=400 $$

Solve  the system $$ \frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1$$  $$48x-125y=400 $$

to find  the two points $(-1.56199, -3.79980)$ and $(4.68293,-1.40176).$

Now we can find the distance from P to these points.

Answer (score 1):

The polar of $(3,-5)$ w.r.t. the ellipse is $$\frac{3x}{25}+\frac{-5y}{16}-1=0.$$ Intersecting the polar and the ellipse you get the tangent points of the two tangents through $(3,-5).$

They are $(\frac{375\sqrt{41}+1200}{769},\frac{144\sqrt{41}-2000}{769})$ and $(\frac{-375\sqrt{41}+1200}{769},\frac{-144\sqrt{41}-2000}{769})$. The rest is just the distance between these points and $(3,-5)$ and the answer is the two lengths $$\frac{3}{769}\sqrt{1249475\pm 33210\sqrt{41}}.$$

> Aside: If you want the equations of the tangents, you can look at the dual conic $25X^2+16Y^2-1=0.$ It intersects the dual line $3X-5Y+1=0$ in two points $$(-\frac{15\sqrt{41}+48}{769},-\frac{9\sqrt{41}-125}{769}),
>  (\frac{15\sqrt{41}-48}{769},\frac{9\sqrt{41}+125}{769})$$ that have duals the tangent lines: $$-\frac{15\sqrt{41}+48}{769}x-\frac{9\sqrt{41}-125}{769}y+1=0$$ and $$\frac{15\sqrt{41}-48}{769}x+\frac{9\sqrt{41}+125}{769}y+1=0.$$

Comment: I would have done like this, but at the same time, I'm conscious that less and less people know these duality issues on conics and quadrics, though there are very abstract lectures on duality...